# How to compare if a folder exists and if it does not exist, create her

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0, windows-scripting

I have the following problem, I need to create a script that compares if the directory exists and if it does not exist, create it. In the linux shell, I use the  parameter `-F` to check if the directory exists. How do I test in PowerShell?

In Linux shell:

```bash
DIR=FOLDER

if [ -f $DIR ]
then
    echo "FOLDER EXIST";
else
    echo "FOLDER NOT EXIST";
    mkdir $DIR
fi
```

How do I make this comparison in Windows PowerShell?

```bsh
$DIRE = "C:\DIRETORIO"

if ( -e $DIRE ) {
    echo "Directory Exists"
} else {
    md DIRETORIO
}
```

Comment: `-e $DIRE` -> `Test-Path $DIRE`

Comment: Thank for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the comments, `Test-Path` is the PowerShell cmdlet you should use to check for the existence of a file or directory:

```
$DIRE = "C:\DIRETORIO"

if ( Test-Path $DIRE ) {
    echo "Directory Exists"
} else {
    md DIRETORIO
}
```

> The Test-Path cmdlet determines whether all elements of the path
>   exist. It returns $True if all elements exist and $False if any are
>   missing. It can also tell whether the path syntax is valid and whether
>   the path leads to a container or a terminal or leaf element.

Comment: Hi! I use this! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You could also use the `New-Item` cmdlet with the `force` parameter, you don't even have to check whether the directory exists:

```
New-Item -Path C:\tmp\test\abc -ItemType Directory -Force
```

Comment: When `-force`d, what happens to an already-extant directory? I generally do not recommend blindly `-force`ing a cmdlet to 'do its thing' unless I specifically want to force a known state.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You are right, maybe I shouldn't recommend it in first place  but Ansgar already provided the right comment. Just wanted to bring up another way to do this which also works (even if the directory already exists).

Comment: if the folder already exists, it carries the command out anyway without affecting it.As in, it doesn't overwrite the folder, because it doesn't need to. It doesn't affect the contents of the folder if it already exists either.

Comment: The command as suggested in answer above is the equivalent to telling PowerShell *Get me a folder object for the path 'C:\tmp\test\abc'. If it already exists, great; if not, create it, and give me that object. I don't care how you do it, just don't delete anything, and make it happen.* I use it in scripts, and it is a clean, safe way to ensure a path exists without causing any harm to existing files or folders. This appears to be exactly what the OP's intent was, even if it's not what they asked for.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks for clarify that and for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks for the help!